# Why user's date joined is shifted

Tags: mysql, django

I am creating a website with django and when I try to create a user I see that his date joined is shifted by one hour.

For instance if I create a user at `2020-03-02 20:58:56` I see in my database that the `date_joined` of the user is `2020-03-02 19:58:56`

in my `settings.py` I have `USE_TZ` set to `True`:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_TZ = True
```

Why I have this shifted time and how to fix this ?

Comment: It is not shifted: the Database stores it (likely) in UTC, and you get it in Paris time in the frontend.

Comment: and it's normal if I do: `print(request.user.date_joined)` I some of my view I get `2020-03-02 19:58:56` in the shell instead of `2020-03-02 20:58:56` ?

Comment: What is this field datatype precisely? DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: @Akina I think datetime, actualy I have `date_joined` like this: `2020-03-02 19:58:56.612057`

Comment: Don't think. Check.

Comment: datetime, I checked